# eventDidMount not being called

Tags: fullcalendar

I attatched the eventDidMount hook to the calendar, but when my events are rendered the eventDidMount never gets called. However, all my other hooks work fine. Are there known issues with eventDidMount that can stop it from functioning? (ie, code placement, etc.)

Comment: It's going to he hard to help you, if there is no piece of code provided. Imo, There are no known issues with this hook.

Comment: @TimWißmann I figured it out, I was running on a version of fullcalendar from 2019. that version did not have the hooks.

Comment: Ah ok, alright!